# POSTMAN - Visalize custom made JSON file

Tags: json, postman, visualize

I am using postman and would like to visualize the response using the visualizer plugin. The problem is that I am running a GET request on an URL and afterwards in "tests", I am running x number of more requests based on the information received in the initial request. Afterwards, I am taking all of the responses and merging them together so that I now have an extended version of JSON request which has more information. I can log it into console and view all of the information.

The customer would like to visualize this information in Postman using the visualizer plugin but it seems that it does not work - anybody know why? Is is because the plugin is made to work based on only the "main" response received after I click the "Send" button? Is there a way to do it?

Thank you and let me know if you need more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The plugin is made to work on whatever you send to. You can even set a new Json on your Tests scripts and render it using `pm.visualizer.set(template, data)`. For example:

```
var data = {
    "data" : [
        {
            "name" : "Postmany"
        }
        ]
};
var template = `
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
        </tr>

        {{#each response.data}}
            <tr>
                <td>{{name}}</td>
            </tr>
        {{/each}}
    </table>
`;
pm.visualizer.set(template, {
    // Pass the responses you need in a single JSON as data
    response: data
});
```

**Response:**

```
Name
------------
Postmany
```

You can try this code on its own.

**Short answer:** Yes you are doing it right, merging your requests on a single JSON, just make sure you are sending it as second parameter and accessing to it correctly on the template.

Comment: Be aware if you are using `postman.setNextRequest()`:
_Note that postman.setNextRequest() only works with the collection runner and Newman where the intent is to run a collection, as opposed to sending a single request._
And the visualize plugin isn't available in Collection Runner

Comment: Yes, this example is simplified. But what I have in tests is that first I run the initial GET request by clicking the SEND button. After that, I take the response (responseBody), and based on the information I have received, I am running more GET requests and in the end, gather all that data and make a new JSON. However, I am not able to visualize that data. If I use that JSON as the "data" parameter on the visualizer plugin, then it does not work.